# Interface definition in package in SystemVerilog

Tags: simulation, system-verilog, interface

I have a very simple `interface` definition in a `package` in SystemVerilog:

```
1 package general_pack;
2     interface diff_i_t ( input p,
3                          input n );
4     endinterface
5 endpackage
```

I added the file into a Vivado project, and then the editor shows an error at line 2:

```
Error: Syntax error near diff_i_t.
```

What's wrong with it? Is this the right way to define interfaces in a `package`?

Answer (score 1):

It is illegal to declare an `interface` inside a `package`.  You need to declare it outside the `package`:

```
interface diff_i_t ( input p,
                     input n );
endinterface

package general_pack;
endpackage
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 26.2 *Package declarations*:

> SystemVerilog packages provide an additional mechanism for sharing
> parameters, data, type, task, function, sequence, property, and
> checker declarations ...

Other simulators provide a more helpful error message:

```
Error-[USVSNM] Unsupported SystemVerilog construct
  Found 'interface' inside package before 'endpackage'. 'interface' inside 
  'package' is not allowed.
```

The above message is from Synopsys VCS, which is available (along with other simulators) on EDA Playground.

Comment: Good to know that. I thought in VHDL way that put such shared definitions inside `package`s. But if it's outside a `package`, how do I refer to it in a different file?

Comment: OK, I saw someone mentioned an `interface` should be treated like a `module` and no need to include the definition like a `package`, just "instantiate" it.

Comment: @fiedel: Yes, in that respect, think of an `interface` more like a `module`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you. @toolic